# Can't launch graphical apps from terminal after updating to 15.10

Tags: command-line, upgrade, 15.10

After updating to 15.10 it's impossible to run graphical apps from terminal:

```
xxx@xxx:~$ gksudo wireshark
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(gksudo:5532): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
xxx@xxx:~$ sudo -H wireshark
[sudo] password for xxx: 
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
** (wireshark:5535): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyFailed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(wireshark:5535): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
xxx@xxx:~$ wireshark
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
** (wireshark:5569): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyFailed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(wireshark:5569): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
xxx@xxx:~$ gedit
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
** (gedit:5570): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyFailed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:5570): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
xxx@xxx:~$ sudo gedit
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
** (gedit:5574): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyFailed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:5574): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

My little research pointed to gksudo using but it ain't working either. I've also tried some stuff with xauth. What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try removing `.Xauthority` - `sudo rm -f ~/.Xauthority` and then restarting.

Comment: Nah, same thing.

Comment: @user423626, thank you! I had this problem after a complete reinstallation and copying over the configuration files from the old system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Odd but `export DISPLAY=:1` helped. Cheers.

Comment: Are you running multiple X displays or something? Default should be `:0`

Comment: exactly the same issue (on 16.04 in my case); unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, only one. ":0" was always default but something changed after update.

Comment: In my case, setting DISPLAY to :0 solved it (while :1 did not)

Comment: In my case, setting DISPLAY to :2 solved it. Just have to keep trying,.

Comment: `export DISPLAY=:1` worked for me. I've had this problem (Ubuntu 20.04) since I installed `nvidia-utils-440` and `nvidia-driver-440`. Another site mentioned the `who` command, which for me does include `:1` twice.

Answer (score 24):

As a regular user, run the command `xhost +`. After that, try running your graphical application again.

This turns off host-based access control on the X server. Here is the relevant information from the man page:

> The xhost program is used to add and delete host names or user names to the list allowed to make connections to the X server.
>
> + Access is granted to everyone, even if they aren't on the  list (i.e., access control is turned off).

Comment: I've had problems where I can open GUI applications from the terminal as `root`, but not as a regular user. In that case, running `xhost +` as `root` allowed me to then start the GUI applications as a regular user.

Comment: This worked! Thanks!

Comment: This works but has security implications. See the answer below about this.

Answer (score 3):

**Warning:** Improper use of xhost can inadvertently give every host on the Internet full access to an X display server.

Generally you shouldn't turn off host-based access control on the X server unless you know what you're doing. Instead you should only allow the things that require access.

#### Solution:

**Execute:** `xhost +si:localhost:root`

The above solution also works for Wayland users executing an elevated XWayland application.

When attempting to run an XWayland application with elevated permissions you may receive the following error:

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Could not parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the same problem found after updating a single package `gnome-shell` through `synaptic-package-manager`. Immediately after next login I was not able to access any GUI part of the OS.
Did lots of searching, finaly,

> when I used `apt install gdm3` from recovery mode terminal, I was able to find a 
>      login prompt after system boot(Only terminal, not GUI).
>
> After that I tried `apt install gnome` which installed a whole bunch of components along, once downloads finished, I was able to get my OS in GUI mode.
>
> If you're not getting login prompt itself then try to follow above
>   step in recovery mode. Otherwise try installing Gnome which updates
>   the gdm3 along.

Answer (score 1):

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

This is what worked for me on 20.04

Answer (score -3):

This worked on Ubuntu 20.10 with gnome 40.4.0

Instead of opening the terminal and typing the command: `gparted`
and being prompted to input password for root (which ended up giving me the error), I simply typed: `sudo gparted` and entered the password in the terminal, [rather than the graphical prompt].

I tried everything listed above and nothing worked, and I said well let me just use `sudo` to begin with...

And it worked.

Comment: It's not so great because using `sudo`  to launch graphical applications is not recommended.