# Unable to open any graphical app with "sudo"

Tags: sudo, mir

Tried to find some answer here: [Can't launch graphical apps from terminal after updating to 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768508/cant-launch-graphical-apps-from-terminal-after-updating-to-15-10), but it didn't solve my problem.

```
$ sudo gedit
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused.

(gedit:4574): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

only `gedit` in terminal works fine. This is my local computer, not a remote system.

Comment: Please copy and paste terminal outputs into your question. Images are annoying to read and aren't searchable.

Comment: Did you try the first comment the question?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/614387/gksu-gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-0

Comment: @Zacharee1 better?

Comment: For me, "sudo gedit" works awesome and I don't need gksudo, despite Zacharee1's insistence it is necessary.  Please add more details. 1) from that terminal, can you run gui as your user, not as root? (what returns from gedit).   2) Is the terminal you are showing us on your LOCAL computer, or is it on a remote workstation?  If you are on remote, then problem is certainly in your SSH forwarding of X11.  Perhaps remote does not offer X11 forwarding, or you didnot ask for it.

Comment: @pauljohn32 only "gedit" in terminal works fine and this is my local computer not remote.

Comment: I would say that Mir is not yet ready for GUI apps that escalate privileges. This may be one of the reasons why making it default was recently delayed (again?). `gksudo` didn't work, because it is designed to work with X11, not Mir. Is there particular reason why you use Mir, or you don't care and are willing to switch back to X11?

Comment: @miroslawZalewski I do not care about"mir" and "x11". I have fresh installed ubuntu 16.04.1 and I did nothing regarding these settings. I just want that "gksudo" or "sudo" with gui should work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but I had the same issue after renaming host after fresh install. I have followed that http://askubuntu.com/a/59517/373070 and rebooted; now both issues are gone.

Comment: Related, though probably not a duplicate, and with Wayland rather than Mir: [Why don't gksu/gksudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-work-with-wayland) (As for `sudo gedit`, that command *shouldn't* be used, though the problem with it turns out not to have been related at all to the problem here. `gksu gedit`, `gksudo gedit`, `kdesudo gedit`, and as needed on systems that don't have gksu(do) or kdesudo , the now-common `sudo -H gedit` or `sudo -i gedit`, are all reasonably safe, but [`sudo gedit` isn't](https://askubuntu.com/q/270006). @pauljohn32)

Answer (score 17):

Older post is below, but is still 100% valid.

Mir is not what one would consider stable/ready for operation. Most of the Ubuntu core (such as the below mentioned `gksudo` and other programs) still relies on X, and can't handle what Mir uses. Until further notice, it's recommended you switch back to X11 unless you have a very good reason to use Mir. If the latter is true, get comfy with `sudo nano`.

---

Repeat after me:

> ## NEVER RUN GRAPHICAL PROGRAMS WITH `sudo`! *

<sup><sup>*except in *extremely* rare cases where you know ***exactly*** what you're doing.... Or you have a thing for pain. Either/or.</sup></sup>

Again. And once more to your dog for good measure.

Instead, use the `gksudo` command to launch a graphical command with root powers, like so:

```
gksudo gedit /var/log/auth.log
```

If your system does not have GKsudo installed on it, install it first with apt:

```
sudo apt install gksudo
```

Note that if you're running KDE, use the equivalent `kdesudo` command.

---

The reasoning behind this is that `sudo` does not preserve user-land permissions, which are very often used by graphical applications. For example, if you change the `gedit` config file after opening it with `sudo`, you'll have an issue where `gedit`'s config file is now owned by root and is unreadable and/or unwriteable to you, the user.

`gksudo` takes care of this for you and handles all of the heavy lifting of ensuring that permissions stay the same and don't break anything.

Console commands are different because they often don't save userland configs, and are designed for the use of `sudo` as opposed to `gksudo`.

Comment: The question they link says `gksudo` doesn't work. I wonder if it works for OP...

Comment: @Zacharee1 I'm not sure either, but it's still good advice that the OP should really be aware of.

Comment: well yeah it is :p

Comment: Thanks for your whole description about "sudo" and "gksudo" but I am getting error after using "gksudo" too..like this

gksudo gedit

(gksudo:5648): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:5656): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: @Akhileshkumar Try rebooting. I think some environment variables got messed up and need to be reset. Display variables should never be null, even with Mir.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself :)

Comment: @KazWolfe rebooting didn't worked..Is it possible that it is because of "BURG" I installed recently or A squid server I made to reduce the hassle of using proxy authentication again and again.

Comment: Akhilesh 's comment just now makes me think problem is that the ssh connection to the remote server did not include X11 forwarding.  Probably little/nothing to do with sudo versus gksudo, more likely X11 forwarding.

Comment: @Akhileshkumar Neither of those would cause this.

Comment: @pauljohn32, you'd be surprised at gksudo vs sudo on this one. Do we know for a fact he's using X11 forwarding?

Comment: @KazWolfe: Question contains the [tag:mir] tag, so I don't even think (s)he is using X11.

Comment: I heard we liked `pkexec` more than gksudo? is that true?

Comment: @cat They do roughly the same thing. `pkexec` is considered more proper, but old habits die hard.

Comment: "cannot open display" sounds very much like an X-related error message :) What happens when a "DISPLAY=:0" is prepended to the privileged command?

Comment: @KazWolfe I had just freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 and did not touched anything related to "X11" or "MIR". Since you are referring that installing "X11" could solve my problem. Please Guide me to do that.