# Synaptic doesn't launch as root

Tags: sudo, synaptic

When I'm trying to launch Synaptic from Application Manager it asks me for password, I'm writing it ( I doube-checked though) and then the software close.

When I'm trying to launch it with `sudo` it doesn't work, and everytime when I'm trying to log in with `su` in terminal, I get `Authentication failure` and I'm writing the correct password. What's wrong??

Output for `sudo -H synaptic`

```
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(synaptic:32380): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: Ubuntu version? Wayland?

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu 17.10 with Wayland, you can use the work-arounds at the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w; Otherwise there is another problem, so please tell us which version you are running.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 16.04.03 I just reinstalled it

Comment: 1. If you start from a terminal window with the command line `sudo -H synaptic` there might be some output (warnings  and error messages). If there are, please edit your original question to show us this output. (Indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as `code`.) ; 2. Also please make your system up to date: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and try again.

Comment: I updated and still not working, I added the output

Comment: There is a problem with Mir. I have not much experience of Mir. You could try the same method, as is used to make it work to run with elevated permissions (with `sudo -H`) in Wayland: See the link in my first comment which is the same link as the 'Possible duplicate of' link. Otherwise, let us hope that someone who knows more about Mir can chip in and help you.

Comment: I found another question at AskUbuntu with an answer that might be relevant for you, https://askubuntu.com/questions/817902/unable-to-open-any-graphical-app-with-sudo; Mir is not what one would consider stable/ready for operation. Most of the Ubuntu core (such as the below mentioned gksudo and other programs) still relies on X, and can't handle what Mir uses. Until further notice, it's recommended you switch back to X11 unless you have a very good reason to use Mir.

Comment: I tried with `gksudo` I also tried with `kdesudo` I get the same errors. But I wonder why Synaptic crash, after I write my password even from the Application search bar, so no terminal commands involved.