# Cannot open any software in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-center, gedit

When ever I try to run any software be it google-chrome or gedit , it doesnt open. When ever I try to open any software using terminal it shows an error
:

```
(Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
** (gedit:8440): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(gedit:8440): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
)
```

Comment: Consider this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199891/invalid-mit-magic-cookie-1-key-when-trying-to-run-program-remotely

Comment: That's a problem with the software you are trying to use talking to the software that manages the gui environment - all the stuff that isn't just plain text on a plain background.  You need to give more details.  Are you booted into a graphical environment? Exactly what command elicited that message? EXACTLY.  You can get error messages like that when trying to run a graphical program as another user with sudo for example. Details matter.

Comment: I just typed the command gedit filename e

Comment: @Lew it was working perfectly fine even if I try to open Google chrome using terminal it shows the same error message ( command - google-chrome) . This command worked earlier.

Comment: You never answered the question "Are you booted into a graphical environment?" I'll assume you are. I'll assume the "terminal" you are typing into is a terminal emulator in  a WINDOW, not a tty. You didn't say how you started the terminal but I'll assume it is as a regular user.  I'll assume you are working on a local machine you can touch, not over a network. All those kinds of details MATTER. But making a huge pile of assumptions, I'd try    `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg`     but YMMV.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't launch graphical apps from terminal after updating to 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768508/cant-launch-graphical-apps-from-terminal-after-updating-to-15-10)