# (gedit:76): Gtk-WARNING

Tags: display, gtk, gedit, connection, init

When I type `gedit filename.c`:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:76): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:57:16.278: cannot open display:
```

This is the error is displayed
and those numbers shown is random everytime I execute it,

when `ls -l ~/.config/gedit`

is entered

`ls: cannot access '/home/blank/.config/gedit': No such file or directory`

is displayed

how to fix this?

Comment: That's because you used gedit with sudo

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `ls -l ~/.config/gedit` command.

Comment: If the file is not owned by you, then `sudo -H gedit /path_to/filename.c`. If you're running in Wayland, either log back into your session using the "Ubuntu" option, or disable Wayland by editing `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @Pilot6  its updated ..hav a look

Comment: That is the problem. Now run it with sudo `sudo ls -l ~/.config/gedit`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't launch graphical apps from terminal after updating to 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768508/cant-launch-graphical-apps-from-terminal-after-updating-to-15-10)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is that `gedit` config files are owned by root.
This happens when you run `sudo gedit` in a terminal, that is wrong.

You can fix it by running

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.config/gedit
```

That will set correct ownership for these files.

Next time if you really need to run `gedit` with `sudo` (not recommended), do it this way:

```
sudo -H gedit
```

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar issue when running Ubuntu on Windows with WSL2.

What it works for me was to to follow the instructions at
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL
paragraph:
Running Graphical Applications

Before I was using Xming, but gedit or any graphical visualization was not working.
Then I tried with VcXsrv and after gedit worked!

https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/